# Pass multiple PHP variables to JS in Options Page

Tags: wp-localize-script

I'm passing variables from options to the front-end using `wp_localize_script`. Issue is that now I have 71 input fields in the options page with these ids: `calc_m_transport_1`, `calc_m_transport_2` and so on till 71.

What would be the efficient way to pass this data to the front-end?

Right now this is how I'm doing it:

```
$phpValues = array(
        'value1' => get_option( 'plugin_name_value1'),
        );
        wp_localize_script( $this->plugin_name, 'phpValues', $phpValues )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking like :

```
$phpValues = array();
for($i=1;$i<=71;$i++){
    $phpValues['value'.$i] = get_option('plugin_name_value'.$i);
}

wp_localize_script( $this->plugin_name, 'phpValues', $phpValues )
```